# Can I turn off the 'Particle Effect' window in 'Scene' view in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system, particles

Is it possible to turn off the Particle Effect window in the Unity IDE?

This view takes up a lot of real estate on the Scene view window.

I'd like to be able to click on a particle effect in my hierarchy **WITHOUT** this Particle Effect window popping up.

[image: Particle Effect window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Unity documentation

> When a GameObject with a Particle System is selected, the Scene view contains a small Particle Effect panel, with some simple controls that are useful for visualising changes you make to the system’s settings.

So I don't think that you can turn this panel off

Answer (score 1):

In the upper part of the scene view there's a Gizmos' dropdown menu. By clicking it, you can turn on/off various Gizmos, including the particle system. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1   Thank you, Andrea. That is helpful. I found Particle System in the menu, but it appears that this menu allows someone to turn on and off the Particle System icon only (not the little window).  Your answer was still helpful to me though because I was not aware of what the Gizmo menu did. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Also, on the left side, where you can toggle the skybox, you have a drop-down menu too (black triangle).
From there you can enable/disable all particles system in scene.

It drives me nuts xD

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, so here is what i did. I created a child gameobject to the one I was attaching the particle system to. Then, I basically grabbed the ParticleSystem from that child gameobject. It works exactly the same way and now, because I don't have to select that child gameobject ever, I can freely select the parent without having to see the Particle Effect window.

Comment: I am going to try this and get back to you. Thanks for the information.